# statusBar options have no effect

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm trying to customize my iOS app's status bar while using react-native-navigation, but they seem to have no effect.

I have tried two different ways to set the options:

In the component function itself:

```
Navigation.mergeOptions(props.componentId, {
    statusBar: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      style: 'dark'
    }
  });
```

As an option:

```
LoginView.options = {
  statusBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    style: 'dark'
  }
};
```

Additionally, I have also tried setting it as default using `Navigation.setDefaultOptions`.

However, none of these have any effect.

I am using RNN 7.15.0 (latest version as of this writing).

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out right after I posted. Needed to "View controller-based status bar appearance" to TRUE in my app's Info.plist